# When will Daedalus show NFT'S?

Tags: nft, native-assets, daedalus

I believe it is already possible to see NFT'S in Yoroi, I am wondering when could we expect similar features in Daedalus.

Answer (score 2):

Right now the only way I know is using pool.pm because Smaug created a metadata specific for this purpose.
The wallets aren't yet fit to the same metadata therefore first, the proposal must be accepted.
I hope it will.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a workaround for this, you could actually use the same recovery phrase from Daedalus on Yoroi and have both instances on your machine. This allows you to take advantage of both wallets.

Answer (score 1):

[*Daedalus v4.4.0*](https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407754202393-Daedalus-4-4-0-release-notes) and higher allows you to see long-awaited NFTs and other tokens in ***Tokens*** tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ADA Monitor App
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esodot.andro.monitor&hl=en-US

Answer (score -1):

If you need it natively supported, you'll have to wait till Alonzo and the launch of smart contracts.

Comment: You can use NFTs even now. There is little difference when ti comes to displaying it in a wallet based on if it is minted by a script or a smart contact.